# How can i beat a timing function in a website that uses php microtime() for start time and submit time?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-services, firefox

I am using an online quiz game with time constraints where when i ask for question set, they reply with questions and there's a "start_time" input present in the html source(probably they sent using microtime() of php). When i submit the form(i.e-questions), possibly they uses that submitted start_time and compares it with the servers current microtime and then uses the duration to determine my answering speed.

Is there any way to beat that timing?

They don't use any cookie, when i request questions with my id(in a text box), they sends questions with my id and start_time embedded in html. So it might be possible to tweak the start_time close to the current time while submitting, i think? but how'd i calculate the closest current_time of server then? any hint will do, though detailed instruction would help a lot.

Comment: Why would we tell you how to cheat something? You should have masked your question if you want an answer that will help you cheat or hack something.

Comment: And you're looking to impress who with your shortest time?

Comment: You can beat it by thoroughly understanding the topic you're answering questions on. :)

Comment: Aww...did I "accidentally" irk you for you to come up with that line?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the value of microtime. (search on source code html)
You'll need php and apache running local.

So you can try:

```
 list($microSec, $timeStamp) = explode(" ", 'microtime value you geted on code');
 echo date('F jS, Y, H:i:', $timeStamp) . (date('s', $timeStamp) + $microSec); //here the actual date from server.
```

Based on your actual date from server, you can :

```
echo microtime('the date you want inject on code'); //date format Y-m-d
```

Now you can use somekind of "firebug" to run javascript/jquery to change the hidden value.

```
jQuery('#input_hidden_id').val('here the value you get on php code');
```

Remember this code isn't tested yet.

Edit: I don't have intention to harm somebody or some code or some system integrity, but i aways have fun "breaking" some security inssue on client side. Like "Wait more 12938721 seconds to download" just "innocent" things. If you use this suggest of code to bad propous its by your risk, and i don't recommend you to do that. Think about other ppl before do some thing stupid.

Comment: And the prize for having no ethical standpoint towards cheating online goes to Guerra, congrats!

Comment: This code can teach developers to think better on security inssue on client side. The bad action is on the action. I don't see nothing bad ethical on breaking some quest integrity ;)

Comment: Well, if you have the appropriate excuse to ensure yourself you haven't helped a wannabe script kiddie / cheater / whatever kind of unfair person causing damage then I guess it's all just fine and dandy in the land of purple unicorns. It's standard practice to help developers devise ways to "beat" online quizzes so it's totally my bad for pointing it out. I'm going to fly away now on my winged purple pony.

Comment: @N.B don't worry yourself with small things man. It's just a Quest. But if you realy want i can delete my answer. But what i said here isn't new or big thing. With a little googling you can get all of these and more. It's better i explain the code and the risk and what is right, and other professional on SO can see what kind of cheat can be made on your codes, or is better he go to other place some kind of hacker forum and learn worst things with bad instructions and propous? Don't be moralist, teach and explain are better than hide and censure

Comment: It's not me wanting you to delete the answer, it's you justifying helping someone who obviously doesn't have good intentions but seeks the way. There's a difference, and it's not me being the moral vertical here, it's just sad that you'll opt to "teach" someone how to break stuff and justify it with "oh he'll go to a hacking forum to find out". Well, let him go there and find out.

Comment: Obviously you don't understand my point of view. @N.B, but don't have problem. Feel free to flag my answer and if SO staff want he can delete it with no problem. But i'm not here to discuss ethical with you.

Comment: Your point of view? You're not reading what I wrote but that's fine, people rarely read and comprehend. It's just sad that you're willing to let go the info to break things for mere virtual reputation on a website. I won't flag your answer or downvote, I'm just disappointed that young people have no morals these days. It's no wonder that we live in a shit world. But hey, I'll move to a purple unicorn world soon, I can tell that you guys live happily over there.

Comment: Ok @N.B i respect your opnion and thanks to share with us. Make me re-think about my action. Next time i'll think 3 times before share some "dangerous" information.